# Angular/Typescript - Fast way to assign object properties between two similar objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two object classes that are very similar and I need to know if there is a way to easily assign all the common property values from object1 to object2.

This is the scenario:

```
let obj1:Product;
left obj2:OffertRow;
```

The common properties for instances are: **idProduct, ProductName**

Is there a way to do something like this in order to pass obj2 properties on obj1 one:

```
obj1 = obj2
```

Or I always have to specify the properties:

```
obj1.idProduct = obj2.idProduct;
obj1.Product = obj2.Product;
.... = ...
```

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's
>   properties names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

```
var obj1 = {}
var obj2 = {}
Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key2 => {
  Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key1 => {
    if (key1 === key2) {
      obj1[key1] = obj2[key1]
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if/when `obj1` doesn't have the `key` property?

Comment: thanks @davidxxx , but the script you provide seems to work for all the properties and not for the common...

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign(obj1, obj2) ist what you are looking for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

EDIT: sorry i thought you we're talking about JSON objects not classes. Wrong answer!

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create an array of the common properties and iterate over it.

```
let commonProps = ['idProduct', 'ProductName'];

commonProps.map(x => {
  obj1[x] = obj2[x]  // or use the spread operator {...obj2[x]} if you need to be more carefull
})
```

---

Alternative solution using `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(obj2)
  .filter(x => Object.keys(obj1).includes(x))
  .map(x => obj1[x] = obj2[x])
```